# Regular expression find and replace tag content

Tags: regex

find and replace tags using regular exp. I have a huge numbers of xml files. I want to find .mp3 files and replace the tag with empty like `<url></url>`

```html
  <url>audio/mod1_s11.mp3</url>
  <url>audio/mod1_s11.wav</url>
```

Comment: regex : `(\S*\.mp3\b)` replace `<url>\1</url>`. Why you choose regex for this job?

Comment: Thanks  Avinash Raj thats worked :)

Comment: done... Posted it as an answer.

Comment: Am using notepad++ editor and there are huge numbers of .xml files. By giving the folder path we can replace the content, for that reason only i used regex. Is there any other better solution for that. Anyway i done the work using regex.

Comment: Accept the working answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a Unix machine and that the data in the XML files are occurring just like you said:

```
$ find . -name "*.xml" -print | \
  while read f; do
   sed -e 's#<url>.*\.mp3</url>#<url></url>#' $f >${f}.tmp
   mv ${f}.tmp $f
  done
```

But usually, regular expressions are not ideal for grokking XML.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex:**

```
(\S*\.mp3\b)
```

`\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters. Here you could use `\S+` also.

**Replacement string:**

```
<url>\1</url>
```